# Code runs for 20min+, then stops with no output, what's the problem?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the 'src' from 500 profile pictures on [Transfermarkt](https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop), the pictures on each players profile that is, not the small picture from the list. I've managed to store each players URL to a list. Now when I'm trying to iterate through it, the code just runs and runs, then stops after 20 minutes something, without any error or output from my print command. As I said, I want the source (src) for each players picture on their respective profile.

I'm not really sure what's wrong with the code, since I don't get any error messages. I've built it with help from different posts here on stackoverflow.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


playerID = []
playerImgSrc = []


result = []

for page in range(1, 21):

    r = requests.get("https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?land_id=0&ausrichtung=alle&spielerposition_id=alle&altersklasse=alle&jahrgang=0&kontinent_id=0&plus=1",
        params= {"page": page},
        headers= {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"}
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    links = soup.select('a.spielprofil_tooltip')

    for i in range(len(links)):
        playerID.append(links[i].get('id'))

    playerProfile = ["https://www.transfermarkt.com/josh-maja/profil/spieler/" + x for x in playerID]

    for p in playerProfile:
        html = requests.get(p).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        link = soup.select('div.dataBild')

    for i in range(len(link)):
        playerImgSrc.append(link[i].get('src'))
print(playerImgSrc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the website `navigation` is using [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) technology, Which is really quick enough, the same as you browsing a folder in your local machine.

Therefore, the `data` displayed within the `UI`(User Interface) is actually coming from a background of [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) request to specific `directory` within the host which is `marktwertetop` where it's using `AJAX`.

I've been able to locate the `XHR` request been made to it, Then I called it directly with the required `parameters` while looping over the `pages`.

I figured out the difference between `small` and `large` photo is actually one different `location` of `direction` which is `small` and `header`, So I've replaced it within in the `url` itself.

Also i considered been under `antibiotic` protection () meant under `requests.Session()` to maintain the `Session` during my `loop` and `downloading` the `pics`, which means to prevent `TCP` layer security from `blocking/refusing/dropping` my `packet/request` while `Scraping/Downloading`.

Imagine, that you already open a `browser`, where you navigate between the same `website` pages, there's a `cookies` `session` created which `established` as long as you connected to the `site`, and if `idle` it's refresh itself.

But the way you were doing it, is just you are open a browser, then close it, then open it again and close it, **AND SO ON** ! where the `server` side count it as `DDOS` attack ?! or flood behavior. and that's a very basics of `firewall` action.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?ajax=yw1&page={}"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        allin = []
        for item in range(1, 21):
            print(f"Collecting Links From Page# {item}")
            r = req.get(url.format(item), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            img = [item.get("src") for item in soup.findAll(
                "img", class_="bilderrahmen-fixed")]
            convert = [item.replace("small", "header") for item in img]
            allin.extend(convert)
    return allin


def download():
    urls = main(site)
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(url, headers=headers)
            name = url[52:]
            name = name.split('?')[0]
            print(f"Saving {name}")
            with open(f"{name}", 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)


download()
```

[image]

**UPDATE** per user comment:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

site = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?ajax=yw1&page={}"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        allin = []
        names = []
        for item in range(1, 21):
            print(f"Collecting Links From Page# {item}")
            r = req.get(url.format(item), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            img = [item.get("src") for item in soup.findAll(
                "img", class_="bilderrahmen-fixed")]
            convert = [item.replace("small", "header") for item in img]
            name = [name.text for name in soup.findAll(
                "a", class_="spielprofil_tooltip")][:-5]
            allin.extend(convert)
            names.extend(name)
    with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Name", "IMG"])
        data = zip(names, allin)
        writer.writerows(data)


main(site)
```

Output: [view online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ba41e349c87464ec02b664f8d72c3bf7/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! That's really helpful. But I don't want to save the image as a jpg. But I want the src tag, the image link, aswell as the player name, in a csv. I'm later going to load it into Qlik Sense, then I want the src link.                  Thanks!

Comment: Your're the best!! Thanks

Comment: If I want to increase the values scraped, could you help me with that?

Comment: Hi, the code does not scrape the correct players, since I can see that some of the players are missing their image.

Comment: do you see this?

Comment: Changed now! :)